# Magento 2 Error After logging in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, error, theme, admin-panel, error-log

An Error code showing After Trying to logging in Admin Panel Only! 
An Error Message showing like: Specified invalid parent id (`Ves_All::ves_all`)

> Error log record number: 1295586411401

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Check this, may help: https://venustheme.ticksy.com/ticket/1216649/

Answer (score 2):

Please check adminhtml/menu.xml to find (Ves_All::ves_all) you should define a  child with id="Ves_All::ves_all).